# Liferay: Ajax request type changed POST to GET, how to switch back

Tags: post, get, liferay

I am facing this issue which started after we updated the JQuery version from 1.2.6 to 1.4.2, to accommodate some of the components we use.
So, the issue here is that earlier the Ajax request for the Flag functionality on Blogs, Message Board portlets was POST and after this update it changed to GET.

Please help to us to understand what triggered this change from POST to GET and how to change is back to POST.

Thanks,
Micheal

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by adding this code to some master js file.  This will set this as the default across all jQuery ajax requests.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    type: "POST"
});
```

Comment: well I know this, but wanted to know where exactly is this piece of code in Liferay, there are muliple locations with this code